# Awesome-CV How to create tables of cv entries spanning multiple pages

Tags: awesome-cv

If for one of the categories of `cventries`, `cvhonors` or `cvskills` the list spans more than one page, how can I avoid that the table is cut beyond what it fits in one page? I believe this has to do with the `awesome-cv.cls` file uses tabular instead of `tabularx` or similar. Thanks for the tip on how to fix this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I do not know `awesome-cv` and even cannot find a user manual for it, but I think a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) could be useful to reproduce the problem.

Comment: End the list and start a new one at the appropriate place.

Comment: I notice that you are using a user provided class.  Since these are not available on CTAN and not part of TeXlive it is impossible to say which version you are using.  These classes are often referred to as "templates" and are only meant to replace their content with yours.  Any modification is beyond their scope.